# Calling swiftUI View from UIKIt and pass data with or without userdefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uikit, combine

I have been trying to call SwiftUI view from UIViewController but i dont know the right way to do it.
I have trying using use Userdefaults but SwiftUI view complains that URL passed via userdefaults is nil

this is the view

```
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook
import UIKit

struct PreviewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    var error: Binding<Bool>
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> QLPreviewController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        controller.isEditing = false
        return controller
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(
        _ uiViewController: QLPreviewController, context: Context) {}
    
    class Coordinator: QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
        var parent: PreviewController
        
        init(parent: PreviewController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(
            in controller: QLPreviewController
        ) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        
        func previewController(
            _ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int
        ) -> QLPreviewItem {
            
            guard self.parent.url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            else {
                return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: parent.url.path)
            }
            defer {
                self.parent.url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            }
            
            return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.parent.url.path)
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct ProjectDocumentOpener: View {
    @Binding var open: Bool
    @State var errorInAccess = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                let url = URL(string: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "documentLink")!)
                PreviewController(url: url!, error: $errorInAccess)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarTitle(
            Text(URL(string: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "documentLink")!)?.lastPathComponent ?? "")
        )
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button("Done") {
                    self.open = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i have been calling it in UIViewController

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(docURL, forKey: "documentLink")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UIHostingController(rootView: ProjectDocumentOpener(open: .constant(true))), animated: true)
```

I tried to google and find a proper resource which explains how to use a SwiftUI view with UIViewController but cant find any resource suitable for my needs.

Comment: I find it very challenging to figure out what you're trying to do here. Would you consider formatting your code and removing the extraneous parts? In general, it's a good strategy to have state owned somewhere in a parent in some sort of `ObservableObject` that gets passed to the child views.

Comment: What is your actual question.  It seems you're having two problems, something with SwiftUI and something with UserDefaults.  It's not clear what the actual question is though.  What is the "docURL" when you store it in the View Controller code?  What is the string returned by `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "documentLink")`. Do they match?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.